# Free CityGML Editor for tag edit

Tags: editing, software-recommendations, citygml

I can view CityGML File in FZKViewer but is there any tool available that allow me to edit cityGML file?

I can easily open cityGML in notepad or notepad++ but its code/tag syntax is not highlighting therefore it is difficult to edit.

Comment: Have you tried to use Notepad++ for XML syntax highlighting to highlight GML? You can do it from `Language -> XML`. GML is an XML grammar to express geographical features.

Comment: My goodness ! it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Notepad++ for XML syntax highlighting to highlight GML. You can do it from `Language -> XML`. GML is an XML grammar to express geographical features.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language):

> The Geography Markup Language (GML) is the XML grammar defined by the
>   Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) to express geographical features.

For more information, you can read about it from above line.